# Aggregate over multiple fields without subaggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents in my ElasticSearch which have two fields. I want to build an aggregate over the combination of these, kind of like in SQL GROUP BY field_A, field_B and get a row per existing combination. I read everywhere that I should use subaggregation for this.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "sales_by_article": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "catalogs.article_grouping",
        "size": 1000000,
        "order": {
          "total_amount": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_amount": {
          "sum": {
            "script": "Math.round(doc['amount.value'].value*100)/100.0"
          }
        },
        "sales_by_submodel": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "catalogs.submodel_grouping",
            "size": 1000,
            "order": {
              "total_amount": "desc"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "total_amount": {
              "sum": {
                "script": "Math.round(doc['amount.value'].value*100)/100.0"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

With the following simplified result:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "sales_by_article": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "19114",
          "total_amount": {
            "value": 426794.25
          },
          "sales_by_submodel": {
            "buckets": [
              {
                "key": "12",
                "total_amount": {
                  "value": 51512.200000000004
                }
              },
              ...
            ]
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

However, the problem with this is that the ordering is not what I want. In this particular case, it first orders the articles based on total_amount per article, and then within an article it orders the submodels based on total_amount per submodel. However, what I want to achieve is to only have the deepest level and get an aggregation for the combination of article and submodel, ordered by the total_amount of this combination. This is the result I would like:

```
{
  "aggregations": {
    "sales_by_article_and_submodel": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "1911412",
          "total_amount": {
            "value": 51512.200000000004
          }
        },
        ...
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have learned I should use [composite aggregates](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-composite-aggregation.html) for this.

Answer (score 0):

It's discussed in the docs a bit here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation

Basically you can use a script to create a term which is derived from each document (using as many fields as you want) at query run time, but it will be slow. If you are doing it for ad hoc analysis, it'll work fine. If you need to serve these requests at some high rate, then you probably want to make a field in your model that is a combination of the two fields you're interested in, so the index is populated for you already.

Example query using the script approach:

```
GET agreements/agreement/_search?size=0
{
    "aggs" : {
        "myAggregationName" : {
            "terms" : {
                "script" : {
                    "source": "doc['owningVendorCode'].value + '|' + doc['region'].value",
                    "lang": "painless"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```